# Select multiple rows in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am having a list in angular js with many rows . I wanted to select multiple rowsin the list and add it to another table .

My code is

```
<li class = "list-group-item listroleitem" ng-repeat='role in roles' ng-click="selectRow(role)
          " ng-class="{selectedRole: role === idSelectedRow}">{{role.roleName}}</li>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.selectRow = function(name){
        $scope.idSelectedRow = name;

    };
```

how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you control the selected rows variable, why not initialise it as an array?

```
$scope.idSelectedRow = [];

$scope.selectRow = function(name){
     if( $scope.idSelectedRow.indexOf(name) > -1 )
        $scope.idSelectedRow.splice($scope.idSelectedRow.indexOf(name), 1);
     else
        $scope.idSelectedRow.push( name );

};
```

And then use this in css:

```
<li class = "list-group-item listroleitem" ng-repeat='role in roles' ng-click="selectRow(role)
          " ng-class="{selectedRole: isSelected( role ) }">{{role.roleName}}</li>




$scope.isSelected = function(some_role){
          return $scope.idSelectedRow.indexOf(role) >-1;
}
```

Comment: How would i deselect ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
<li class = "list-group-item listroleitem" ng-repeat='role in roles' ng-click="selectRow(role)
        " ng-class="{selectedRole: role.selected==true}">{{role.roleName}}---{{role.selected}}</li>

function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.roles = [{roleName:"abc"}, {roleName:"dc"}]
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.selectRow = function(role){
        role.selected = !role.selected;
    };
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/30783/